# Import data from a view into a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a view called ss1 which has email,address,city, name and id extracted from two tables and combined in the view.

I want to import this data from the view to an actual physical table. Please advise how I can do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use inner join two tables and export them

Comment: Can you give me an example. I have already used the inner join in the view select statement. Would appreciate a more clear example if possible.

Comment: how is your import data format??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Insert Into:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
select *
from ss1
```

Comment: Thanks nacho, I have tried that statement in mysql workbench but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First you need to create the **new_table** with the same columns you have in your view

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `CREATE TABLE` command itself as:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT * FROM ss1
```